# Change Layout in Landscape with out destroying and recreating Activity

Tags: android, android-orientation

Hi Everyone iam new to android and stuck with the orientation problem i need to display separate layout in landscape and portrait which i designed separately and placed in layout-large and layout-large-land folders now i need to change layout when device is rotated to landscape with out destroying and recreating the Activity

please help me get out of this problem

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

my advice as a long time Android programmer is:

**Don't do it!**

Let the activity be destroyed and re-built with the correct layout.

Just search and research on all the several methods of keeping the data during orientation changes and apply them to your specific case. Below a few to illustrate:

1. the `onCreate(Bundle)` receives that bundle that contains information saved during onSavedInstances(Bundle);
2. User a fragment without a UI (do not call onCreateView) and set it to be retained across rotation with `setRetainInstance(true)` and use it to remember the data
3. use the [Loader pattern](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) to automatically receive the data it was generated on the previous activity

Comment: thanks Budius but my application getting crash by showing android.view.inflateException when i unlock configchanges

Comment: so you should try to fix that bug instead of creating a hack that is completely against all the nice automated methods that the platform provides you.

Comment: if i unlock orientation configchanges i get a performance issue since it need to reload the complex list fragment once again

Comment: that does sounds like a case of using the Loader I mentioned on item 3.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
layout-large-land
```

with

```
layout-land-large
```

***Prevent activity from recreating/destroying***

Add attribute `android:configChanges="orientation"` to the activity declaration in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

The purpose of the `android:configChanges` attribute is to prevent an activity from being recreated when it's really required.

Let me know if it works for you..

Comment: iam getting error mark on that folder and i try to run "Your project contains errors please fix them before running "

Comment: Hope you have created folder inside res folder?

Comment: create a layout file inside that folder and try it to run it

Comment: iam using ADT Bundle (Eclipse JUNO) for creating

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

Add this code in your mainfest.xml each and every activity.

```
android:ConfigChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: i did the same but i need to change the layout when device is rotated to landscape

Comment: This is an anti-pattern and must be discouraged. You HAVE to manage the scenario where activity is recreated, since it happens not only when the device is rotated, but when the SO kills activity to release memory. Manage your layout configuration changes and activity recreation using Loaders or ViewModel and Lifecycle components.